# I installed ubuntu with windows, and windows don't load

Tags: grub2

grub shows that there is Windows, but when I click on it, it showing me a black screen with a dash at top-left; and then sending me back to grub
what can I do? please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you are able to "click" on the GRUB Boot screen.  Have you already tried '`update-grub`'?

However, to fix Windows boot, insert a Windows bootable repair/recovery media and attempt to fix the MBR.  There should be a utility to scan your active Windows installation and then rewrite MBR. For example, Windows 7 and 8 has a `bootrec` utility.

Once it is done and you are able to load Windows, then you will need to attempt to repair grub which should pick up your valid Windows entry from MBR.

Comment: so I need to insert a windows 7 disc and then repair it from the boot menu?

Comment: First try, update-grub from your Ubuntu.  If that fails then yes, you will need to use Windows 7 disc to boot and switch to Recovery Environment and from there run bootrec /ScanOS.  It should find your Windows installation.  If yes, then do a bootrec /fixmbr.  You can get the list of options by saying bootrec /? in the Recovery Environment.